# Oracle Package inside a CLOB with length > 32767 characters. How to "execute immediate" it?

Tags: oracle, package, clob, execute-immediate

Please suppose that I have a package creation script stored inside a table ALPHA, in a column BETA of type CLOB.  The CLOB length is > 32767 characters.

Using PL/SQL code, I would like to "execute immediate" the package creation script.

I could I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

**I am using Oracle 10G**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute immediate` didn't support CLOBs [until 11gR2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#CHDGIGFJ). You can use `DMBS_SQL` to handle larger statements. In earlier versions you could build up the statement, but 11g allows you to [parse a CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_sql.htm#i997676).

There is an example [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=505).

Creating a package dynamically seems like an odd requirement though.

---

Since you're on 10g, you will need to use the [version of DBMS_SQL.PARSE that lets you build up large statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i997676):

> The PARSE procedure also supports the following syntax for large SQL
>   statements:
>
> ```
> DBMS_SQL.PARSE ( 
>    c                  IN   INTEGER, 
>    statement          IN   VARCHAR2S, 
>    lb                 IN   INTEGER, 
>    ub                 IN   INTEGER, 
>    lfflg              IN   BOOLEAN, 
>    language_flag      IN   INTEGER);
> ```
>
> Note: The procedure concatenates elements of a PL/SQL table statement
>   and parses the resulting string. You can use this procedure to parse a
>   statement that is longer than the limit for a single VARCHAR2 variable
>   by splitting up the statement.

An example of that approach [here](http://learnfrommike.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/dynamically-execute-sql-statement.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for having helped me :-)